Understanding the Performance Benefits of CPU Caches When Cache Line Fetch Latency Equals Main Memory Access Time
I'm trying to grasp the performance advantages of CPU caches, particularly in scenarios where fetching a cache line (e.g., 64 bytes) from main memory to the cache incurs the same latency as directly accessing main memory because we are just fetching from memory at the end,So i am having really difficult understanding the benefits of cache(spatial locality).
(By the way i feel the advatages of cache when it is used for frequently accessed datas but here I don't get the advantage of caching the next block of instructions(spatial locality)).

Because programs don't access 64B of data regularly, but they do access objects close in memory (e.g. from a struct or an array). Transferring 64B can exploit the DRAM burst mode (instead of the full column selection each time).
